# How to get results of multiple query?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm doing a social media app. When I follow people I save a "Follow object to server like this:

```
ParseObject follow = new ParseObject("Follow");                       
followquery.put("owner",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
followquery.put("who",otherUser);
```

But I want to get post of followed persons. Something like this:

```
ParseQuery followingsQuery = new ParseQuery("Follow");
//get people i follow
followings.whereEqualTo("owner",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

ParseQuery getpost = new ParseQuery("Post");
//get posts that shared by a person that i follow
getpost.whereEqualTo("user",followingsQuery);
getpost.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

    }
});
```

I want something like this how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `whereMatchesQuery`. Using the case below in your case your innerquery will be your followers and your query the posts.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-queries

Extract from docs

> If you want to retrieve objects where a field contains a ParseObject
>   that matches a different query, you can use whereMatchesQuery. In
>   order to find comments for posts containing images, you can do:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
innerQuery.whereExists("image");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
query.whereMatchesQuery("post", innerQuery);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
  }
});
```